# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in angular 4

Tags: angular

I am totally new in Angular 4 and trying to make clear basic structure of a simple project. I already test my project and it works good yesterday. But today when I open my project and want to do "ng serve" it shows below error. Don't know what is the problem.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at createSourceFile (C:\Users\IR\Desktop\angular-first-project\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:15457:109)
at parseSourceFileWorker (C:\Users\IR\Desktop\angular-first-project\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:15389:26)
at Object.parseSourceFile (C:\Users\IR\Desktop\angular-first-project\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:15338:26)
at Object.createSourceFile (C:\Users\IR\Desktop\angular-first-project\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:15192:29)
at VirtualFileStats.getSourceFile (C:\Users\IR\Desktop\angular-first-project\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\compiler_host.js:66:35)
at WebpackCompilerHost.getSourceFile (C:\Users\IR\Desktop\angular-first-project\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\compiler_host.js:213:38)
at findSourceFile (C:\Users\IR\Desktop\angular-first-project\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:67909:29)
at processImportedModules (C:\Users\IR\Desktop\angular-first-project\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:68056:25)
at findSourceFile (C:\Users\IR\Desktop\angular-first-project\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:67937:17)
at processSourceFile (C:\Users\IR\Desktop\angular-first-project\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:67840:27)
at processRootFile (C:\Users\IR\Desktop\angular-first-project\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:67728:13)
at C:\Users\IR\Desktop\angular-first-project\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:67018:60
at Object.forEach (C:\Users\IR\Desktop\angular-first-project\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:1449:30)
at Object.createProgram (C:\Users\IR\Desktop\angular-first-project\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:67018:16)
at AotPlugin._setupOptions (C:\Users\IR\Desktop\angular-first-project\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:129:28)
at new AotPlugin (C:\Users\IR\Desktop\angular-first-project\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:26:14)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Actually what is the problem I can't understand, Don't know Which code I should give here :(

Comment: search for length keyword in your code and tryn logging it to console before you actually use if its undefined you will get to know where is the error. I would suggest that before trying to use length of an array just put a condition to check whether the length is 0 or not so that you can avoid such errors.

Comment: Problems does not seems anything with your code just `open terminal` OR `CMD` and run a command `npm install` might be a solution

Comment: @Manish search for length keyword really sounds strange but the error explains 'length' of undefined means its says array length is not defined no relation with searching length keyword

Comment: @mayur yes i know it sounds starnge but when he does not even know which part of code is throwing the error the what other option is he left with?

Comment: I had this as well. Some were due to typos or missing properties in json config files or unresolvable path in ///<reference path /> directives. The error message is useless :/ you just know somethings wrong

Answer (score 7):

I have seen this types of errors at random occasions, e.g. after moving components to different folders, even after all references was chagned to match a new path.

Rebuilding project with **ng-build** should help.

Comment: Thanks man :) I have met with the same problem when I changed the location of my service and I have applied "ng serve" again and it worked well.. ng build also will work. Small things giving big headache and answers like these will give us some breathe in the end :)

Answer (score 3):

I had that same issue. 
I supposed it is typescript version issue. I changed also by installing upper and lower version of current version non of them worked. Finally i a solution from github saying:-

There was no **environments** **folder** in the project.

one i added it started working.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

yes I have changed folders and getting that error. After building it worked

Comment: should be comment

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on a development environment where I start the app with `ng serve` controlled by a `systemd` user service. After I restart the user service with `systemctl --user restart <myappservice>` it was running again as expected. This is virtually like canceling the `ng serve` and calling that command again.

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue. I couple of way to fix it

Assign data as an Array

```
data = []
```

in html

```
*ngIf="data.length"
```

Use ?

```
*ngIf="data?.length"
```